# Nested Data querying in Sails+Waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In Sails+Waterline, I am stuck with querying:
Model is as follows:

```
Task: {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Task1",
    "Project":{
        "id":"P1",
        "name":"Project1"
    }
}
```

Here Task has Project as its model (Each task will be associated with a project).
TO get list of all tasks by projectId, I tried doing following:

```
Task.find({project.id:"P1"}, function(err, res){
 //Err or Res
})
```

Above code did not work for me and gave error "Unexpected Token ." for project.id

Is there any way I can get list of tasks using projectId here?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried `Task.find({"Project.id":"P1"}`?

Comment: I tried double quotes, It is not giving me error now but still its not giving response data, Res is undefined

Comment: Then check your error callback...

Comment: Error is null and response is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue, Since project is a model for Task, ProjectId can be directly obtained from it.
i.e. I can directly give

```
Task.find({project:"P1"}, function(err, res){
  //Getting response
})
```

where project holds projectId.
Anyways Thanks for looking into this issue